# NSString (pointer/non pointer) assign or retain

Tags: objective-c

I have four variations of the same class.

A mix of pointer, non-pointer, assign vs copy.

What are the implications of using each case?

1)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain);
@end
```

2)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign);
@end
```

3)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString *apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain);
@end
```

4)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString *apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign);
@end
```

Comment: another option to consider is (nonatomic, copy), which will (obviously) copy the string instead of retaining or assigning it.

Answer (score 9):

1)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain);
@end
```

You cannot allocate `NSObjects` on the stack or as object instance variables. In its early days, Objective-C did allow this, but it doesn't anymore. This code is incorrect.

2)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign);
@end
```

You cannot allocate `NSObjects` on the stack or as object instance variables. In its early days, Objective-C did allow this, but it doesn't anymore. This code is incorrect.

3)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString *apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain);
@end
```

You are retaining an ownership stake in the `NSString` instance, guaranteeing that it will not be deallocate while you retain that ownership. Since `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`, you may have been given a mutable string at assignment, so other code may modify the string's value without your knowledge (unless you are using Key-Value Observing to observe those changes). For this reason, it is *usually* appropriate to use `copy` semantics for properties that you intend to hold an immutable value (`NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, `NSSet` are the common--though not exaustive--suspects).

4)

```
@interface fruit:NSObject{
NSString *apple;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign);
@end
```

You are *not* retaining an ownership interest in the string, meaning that it may be deallocated without your knowlege. In reference-counting environments, this is the standard practice for delegate properties, since retaining them would likely create a retain cycle. The code that is responsible for deallocating the string must set your apple property to nil before doing so (in a ref-counted environment). In a GC environment, your assignment will keep the string alive if you have a __strong pointer or give you a zeroing (set to 0 at dealloc) if you have a __weak pointer in your declaration.

Comment: Thanks alot man,

What do you mean by "You cannot allocate NSObjects on the stack"?
stack means a special place in memory?
And because i'm passing a non pointer

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge you should always use either retain or copy with an NSString*.  Assign on a pointer (4) will not increment the reference count, so will leak memory or rather it would mean you end up accessing released memory as the count would prematurely reach 0.

I don't know if you can use NSString as a native type.  I always use it as a pointer.

Comment: NSString is an object, but just wondering if it's possible to use assign on it even though it's not advisable. Yeah makes sense about the memory leak.

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-pointer object variable in Objective-C. Try to compile a program with one and it will let you know that.